# Word for increasing complexity or image resolution?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word (verb) which means 'increasing the complexity of the structure' or 'increasing the image size/resolution?'

I thought of *tessellate* but its meaning is not exactly what I need. Also, I think it's more related to surfaces of 3D objects, whereas I'm working with 2D.

Comment: Perhaps [***Mandelbrotian***](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-11564766), or even ***fractal***. What's the exact context and meaning again?

Comment: Complexity and higher resolution can be quite different things.

Comment: I'm afraid Mandelbrotian or fractal are unrelated here. See a good dictionary.

Comment: @TRomano In the given context, they *are* related.

Comment: You've mentioned increasing three distinct aspects: the *complexity*, the *resolution*, and the *size*. Since in general these aspects can each be increased *independently*, we'll need more context to understand how they're related in your situation, before we can make any appropriate suggestions.

Comment: I need a verb, not an adjective. I'm programming a function which will increase resolution of a 2D image. I wanted to call the function something smarter than just "IncreaseResolution()"

Comment: [Enhance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LhF_56SxrGk)

Comment: +1 for the sense of humor, Matt Эллен. But I'm not "enhancing" the image in the sci-fi meaning. I'm just making a small image bigger in size (plus recalculating other, invisible properties like the dpi value)

Comment: There are various ways to increase the resolution so that may be why there isn't a specific single verb for it. There are general words you can use in the context.

Comment: You're doing at least two operations: you're **resizing** the image, then **interpolating** to fill in the missing pixels.  Toss in the other properties like DPI, and you're **rescaling** the image.

Comment: Yep, right now I'm using the word "upscale" but AFAIR it doesn't exist (I probably made it up myself). Update: Just checked and it does exist but has a slightly different meaning (it's an adjective and not a verb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for "*upsample*", which is like *resample* but specifically for "making more pixels" (in the context of raster images), and is the opposite of *downsample*.

*Interpolation* does not necessarily mean upsampling, because downsampling also uses interpolation.

Also be advised that strictly speaking - you're not enhancing, you're not increasing complexity, you're not necessarily increasing resolution. Even more strictly speaking - you're not necessarily increasing the size either.

You're "stretching" (wrong term, but perhaps more natural) an image with a specific amount of pixels across a larger amount of pixels.

Comment: Yeah, this sounds most accurate for what I'm doing. I've used "upscale" but that doesn't tell more specifically how I'm doing it. "Upsample" might be more specific

Answer (score 1):

**Elaborate**, meaning *to work out in fine detail*.  It doesn't have quite the right connotations, but the definition matches.

Answer (score 0):

I believe "Interpolation" is to increase the resolution of an image by calculating a value in-between two other values. Its not really increasing complexity though.

Comment: Interpolation is about averaging values. You can interpolate without changing the resolution (you will get a sort of blurring then).

Answer (score 0):

You [wrote](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/210455/word-for-increasing-complexity-or-image-resolution/210467#comment447622_210455):

> *But I'm not "enhancing" the image in the sci-fi meaning. I'm just making a small image bigger in size (plus recalculating other, invisible properties like the dpi value)*

You're looking for ***zoom***.

Comment: Not sure about that. Zoom sounds like you're just closing in whereas I am modifying (enlarging) the image permanently

Comment: Do you just want *enlarge* then? That's been the term of art in photography for decades.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe I am looking too far and trying to come up with something too accurate for my algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Also consider:

• *upsize*, “To make larger or more numerous” — [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/upsize)
• *upgrade*, in sense “to replace an existing object with something better” — [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/upgrade)
• *complexify*, “To make something more complex; to complicate” — [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/complexify#Verb)
• *transmogrify*, “To completely alter the form of” — [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/transmogrify#Verb)
• *embiggen*, “(rare, nonstandard) To enlarge or grow; to make or become bigger” — [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/embiggen#Verb)
• *swell*, “To cause to become bigger” — [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/swell#Verb)
• *aggrandize*, “To make great; to enlarge; to increase” — [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aggrandize#Verb)
• *enlarge* [previously mentioned in a comment], “To make larger” — [en.wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/enlarge#Verb)